# Procedure to accurately extract the instantaneous velocity and spin information from experimental position data?

Tags: velocity, angular-velocity, optimization

I have the time information of 3D position data (discrete) of a sports ball in flight, and I'm attempting to extract the velocity and spin information just using that data as I believe every trajectory has 3 unique velocity and spin initialisations. To eliminate unwanted noise from this data, I applied least squares fitting to write the position components in the x, y, and z dimensions as fourth-order polynomials of time. I calculated the instantaneous velocity by finding the derivatives of these polynomial expressions. All the codes included in this discussion are written in MATLAB.

```
fps = 1080;
global numfps t Vel x y z Pos
numfps = fps;
OriginalData = 0.001*readmatrix('FootballElevation_3DPts.csv','NumHeaderLines',1);
x=OriginalData(50:350,3);
y=OriginalData(50:350,4);
z=OriginalData(50:350,2);

order = 2;

t = (0:1/fps:(length(x)-1)/fps)';

% Symbolic variable for time
syms tt;

% Define the position vector
Pos_sym = [tt.^(order:-1:0)];

% Take the derivative to get the velocity vector
Vel_sym = diff(Pos_sym, tt);

% Take the derivative of velocity to get the acceleration vector
Acc_sym = diff(Vel_sym, tt);


Time = [t.^(order:-1:0)];

Xcoeff = Time\x;
Ycoeff = Time\y;
Zcoeff = Time\z;

Rsq_x = 1 - sum((x - Time*Xcoeff).^2)/sum((x - mean(x)).^2);
Rsq_y = 1 - sum((y - Time*Ycoeff).^2)/sum((y - mean(y)).^2);
Rsq_z = 1 - sum((z - Time*Zcoeff).^2)/sum((z - mean(z)).^2);

% Convert the symbolic expressions to anonymous functions for numerical evaluation
Pos_fun = matlabFunction(Pos_sym*[Xcoeff Ycoeff Zcoeff], 'Vars', tt);
Vel_fun = matlabFunction(Vel_sym*[Xcoeff Ycoeff Zcoeff], 'Vars', tt);
Acc_fun = matlabFunction(Acc_sym*[Xcoeff Ycoeff Zcoeff], 'Vars', tt);

% Evaluate the position, velocity, and acceleration at the sample points
Pos = Pos_fun(t);
Vel = Vel_fun(t);
if order == 2
    Acc = repmat(Acc_fun(t), length(x), 1);
else
    Acc = Acc_fun(t);
end
```

Then, I attempted to extract the spin (assumed constant value owing to the very short time of flight) in two different methods. The ball's trajectory is governed by Newton's equation of motion.

\begin{equation}
 Ma = Mg - 0.5 \rho U U S C_D + \rho R^3 \Omega \times U C_\Omega
\end{equation}

1. Separating the lift term from the above equation and calculating the 3 spin components. I have to rely on the least squares solution as the data from any single position leads to a singular matrix (Ai in the following code)

   ```
    AAA=[];
    BBB=[];
    for i=1:length(x)-1
    g = 9.81; [m/s^2] 
    %Re(i) = norm(Vel(i,:))*2*r/nyu;
    rho=1.2;       % air density [kg/m^3]
    nyu = 1.48*10^(-5); %kinematic viscosity [m^2/s]

    %ball parameters
    r=0.1178;        %big red ball radius [m]
    A=pi*r^2;  %projected or frontal area of the ball [m^2]
    M=0.0335;       %big red mass [kg]

    %default lift coefficient
    Comega=1.7;

    %other parameters
    tau = 3*M/(5*24.5*pi*r*nyu);
    alpha = 2;
    beta = 0;

    %data input from plot
    RevsCd = readmatrix('RevsCd.xlsx');
    Re_data=RevsCd(:,1);
    Cd_data=RevsCd(:,2);

    %Reynolds Number
    Re(i) = norm(Vel(i,:))*2*r/nyu;

    Cd(i) = (interp1(Re_data,Cd_data,Re(i)));

    Ai = [0 Vel(i,3) -Vel(i,2);-Vel(i,3) 0 Vel(i,1);Vel(i,2) -Vel(i,1) 0];
    Bi = [(1/(rho*r^3*Comega))*(M*Acc(i,:)'-M*[0;-g;0]+0.5*rho*A*Cd(i)*norm(Vel(i,:))*Vel(i,:)')];
    AAA = [AAA;Ai];
    BBB = [BBB;Bi];
    end
    Spin_Vector = AAA\BBB
   ```
2. The acceleration equation can be integrated using ODE89 to simulate the trajectory if the initial conditions are known. Using the extracted velocity, I employed the "patternsearch" global optimisation technique to find the spin that best fits the experimental trajectory.

```
  curr_pars = [0 0 0];%spin initialization
  
  initial_error = Err(curr_pars);
    
  options=optimoptions('patternsearch','Display','iter','PlotFcn',
  @psplotbestf);
  tic
  A = [];
  b = [];
  Aeq = [];
  beq = [];
  lb = [];
  ub = [];
  nonlcon = [];
  [curr_pars,fval] =patternsearch(@Err,curr_pars,
  A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options);
  
  [ttt,yy0] = ode89(@path1,t,[Pos(1,1);Pos(1,2);Pos(1,3); ...
  Vel(1,1);Vel(1,2);Vel(1,3)],[],curr_pars);
  
  [ttt,yy] = ode89(@path1,t,[Pos(1,1);Pos(1,2);Pos(1,3); ...
  Vel(1,1);Vel(1,2);Vel(1,3)],[],Spin_Vector);
  
  
  
  %%
  function [P] = Err(curr_pars)
  
  
  global Vel numfps t x y z Pos
  
  
  [ttt,yy] = ode89(@path1,t,[Pos(1,1);Pos(1,2);Pos(1,3); ...
  Vel(1,1);Vel(1,2);Vel(1,3)],[],curr_pars);
  error = (yy(:,3)-Pos(:,3)).^2+(yy(:,2)-Pos(:,2)).^2+
  (yy(:,1)-Pos(:,1)).^2;
  
  
  P = norm(error);
  
  end
  
  
  %%
  function ydot = path1(t,y,curr_pars)
  %physical parameters
  
  ox = curr_pars(1);
  oy = curr_pars(2);
  oz = curr_pars(3);
  g=9.81;       %[m/s^2]
  rho=1.2;       % air density [kg/m^3]
  nyu = 1.48*10^(-5); %kinematic viscosity [m^2/s]
  
  %ball parameters
  r=0.1178;        %big red ball radius [m]
  A=pi*r^2;  %projected or frontal area of the ball [m^2]
  M=0.0335;       %big red mass [kg]
  
  %default lift coefficient
  Csigma=1.7;
  
  %other parameters
  tau = 3*M/(5*24.5*pi*r*nyu);
  alpha = 2;
  beta = 0;
  
  %data input from plot
  RevsCd = readmatrix('RevsCd.xlsx');
  Re_data=RevsCd(:,1);
  Cd_data=RevsCd(:,2);
  % Re = sqrt(y(4)^2+y(5)^2+y(6)^2)*2*r/nyu;
  % Cd = interp1(Re_data,Cd_data,Re)
  % global ox oy oz
  % % ox=50;
  % % oy=100;
  % % oz=-50;
  
  
  ydot = [y(4);y(5);y(6);(-0.5*rho*A*interp1(Re_data,Cd_data,   (sqrt(y(4)^2+y(5)^2+y(6)^2)*2*r/nyu))/M)*sqrt(y(4)^2+y(5)^2+y(6)^2)*y(4)+(rho*r^3*Csigma*oy/M)*y(6)-(rho*r^3*Csigma*oz/M)*y(5);(-0.5*rho*A*interp1(Re_data,Cd_data,(sqrt(y(4)^2+y(5)^2+y(6)^2)*2*r/nyu))/M)*sqrt(y(4)^2+y(5)^2+y(6)^2)*y(5)+(rho*r^3*Csigma*oz/M)*y(4)-(rho*r^3*Csigma*ox/M)*y(6)-g;(-0.5*rho*A*interp1(Re_data,Cd_data,(sqrt(y(4)^2+y(5)^2+y(6)^2)*2*r/nyu))/M)*sqrt(y(4)^2+y(5)^2+y(6)^2)*y(6)+(rho*r^3*Csigma*ox  /M)*y(5)-(rho*r^3*Csigma*oy/M)*y(4)];

  end
```

But neither of the methods gave me a spin that, when combined with the extracted velocity, matches the experimental trajectory reasonably well. So, I wonder if the velocity obtained via the position derivative or FDM doesn't represent reality. I can't think of a reason why position derivative shouldn't give me actual velocity inspite of the presence of spin in the problem. Also, I would be thankful if someone can guide me through any standard velocity and spin extraction procedures if the above method won't work for whatever reason.